# iron-router sub manager still on Spark

Tags: meteor, iron-router

This branch which contains the 'caching' my project needs has not been updated to run on Blaze.
If you install it, it will crash with a 'Spark not defined'
It hasn't been touched in a couple of months.

Is this branch going to move forward or is it dead?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better to ask in the issue tracker on github?

Comment: The sub-manager branch is being worked on by https://github.com/arunoda for his [fast-render](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-fast-render/) package. Perhaps you can get him to update the branch to Blaze and check on his progress.